# hardware-assissted virtulization

Tags: virtualization

I have windows ultimate 7. trying to get xp going. It states my computer does not have hardware-assissted virtulization. It is hp G70=457CA. How can I get hardware assisted virtulization?

Answer (score 1):

According to HP [specifications](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329743-3848802-3848802-3944997-3979150.html), your CPU is Intel Pentium Processor T4300 (1M Cache, 2.10 GHz, 800 MHz FSB).

But Intel [specifications](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=37253) for this CPU says : "Intel Virtualization Technology - No".

So, I'm sorry, but your model doesn't seem to support hardware assisted virtualization.
You might have a last effort look in your BIOS (Del or F2 or F12 while booting), but if Virtualization is not there (might have other names), then it's certain that it doesn't exist for your computer model.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware assisted virtualization is a feature of the CPU. You have to have a CPU that supports it, and it must be enabled in the BIOS.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD-V#AMD_virtualization_.28AMD-V.29) has some information about which AMD and Intel chips have hardware assisted virtualization.